# How to Convert Guid Hex format to byte[16]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have GUID Hex, example: ac865c7313e3e347b6c93c9da39ee2c7
I need to bring him to byte[16].
How can I do that?

Guid.ToByteArray() - Not suitable because "-" is taken into account there

Why different byte arrays?
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no `'-'` character in your example. Please post an actual complete code example (including the types you are dealing with).

Comment: Everything is correct, because it is in this format in the storage.  Its standard form is like this 735C86AC-E313-47E3-B6C9-3C9DA39EE2C7

Comment: You should [edit] your question and post a [mre].

Comment: @JonnyJon44 what is correct? And what's the actual problem? `Guid.Parse` will handle both the separated and unseparated format. `Guid.ToByteArray()` returns the `byte[16]` array you want, not a string with dashes. A byte array has no format

Comment: What do you mean by "the format in the storage"? This question is not answerable in it's current format.

Comment: ac865c7313e3e347b6c93c9da39ee2c7 is located in the database and is returned from there in the format byte[16].

Comment: 735C86AC-E313-47E3-B6C9-3C9DA39EE2C7 comes from outside, and when I compare byte[16] they are not equal

Comment: I need to compare them by byte[16]

Comment: Those guids are different though, why would you expect them to be the same?!

Comment: And if you parse them into a proper `Guid` object, you don't need to use byte arrays to compare them.

Comment: I made a mistake and gave incorrect values, I added images to the question for clarity

Comment: The images only show you already hadthe `byte[16]` buffer you want. Not only does `ToByteArray()` return a `byte[16]`, but the only way `BitConverter.ToString` would work is if you *already* had a `byte[16]` with the GUID's data. You didn't perform any conversion

Answer (score 2):

Do it in two steps,

1. Parse your hex GUID into Guid

   ```
   //This step is missing in your question.
   var guid = Guid.Parse("ac865c7313e3e347b6c93c9da39ee2c7");
   ```
2. Now Convert into `Byte[]`

   `var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();`

[Try here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uogh56)

---

From the comment, it looks like you would like to compare two Guids, then try [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.equals?view=net-8.0) method

```
Guid guid1 = Guid.Parse("ac865c7313e3e347b6c93c9da39ee2c7");
Guid notMatching = Guid.Parse("735C86AC-E313-47E3-B6C9-3C9DA39EE2C7");
Guid sameAsGuid1 = Guid.Parse("ac865c7313e3e347b6c93c9da39ee2c7");
    
Console.WriteLine(guid1.Equals(notMatching));  //False
Console.WriteLine(guid1.Equals(sameAsGuid1));  //True
```

Comment: I think OP already has a proper `Guid` object but is confused as to the presence of the hyphens when it is displayed.

Comment: @DavidG, I agree as he is trying `.ToByteArray()` that means he must have instance of Guid.

Comment: I made a mistake and gave incorrect values, I added images to the question for clarity

Comment: @JonnyJon44 the images don't clarify anything. They show that you already had the `byte[16]` array you wanted in `test.RegistrationGuid`